# OpenCV Video/Image stitching from camera movement. SIFT not enough features?

Tags: opencv, sift, image-stitching

I am trying to register images that are extracted from short movies with continuous camera movement. 
I have the 'usual' pipeline with detect -> match -> clean matches -> homography working. The results with the typical SIFT-example (Basmati, Cookiebox ...) works very well. 
My images 
a) do not result in many features
b) are very close to identical
c) might include large similar areas (walls)

Questions
1) is there some different approach that you would suggest? Esp when continuous movement can be assumed and the images are very similar.
2) how can i implement an initial guess (identity, simple scroll ...), to optimize what 'findHomography" calculates?
3) What analysis/filter of the matches (see image) would you suggest? PCA might be helpful with the constraint of camera pan movements?
4) other things i'm missing/doing wrong?

These images shows aaverage to worse results. (Green lines to the right are the transformed quad. Ignore the small green line in the center) Some pairs get a lot worse registration.
http://www.cs.hs-rm.de/~schweitz/siftmatch.jpg
 
http://www.cs.hs-rm.de/~schweitz/siftmatch2.jpg
 
h**p://www.cs.hs-rm.de/~schweitz/siftmatch3.jpg